# Scrapy: Unsuccessful iterating over a list and pagination

Tags: python, python-2.7, pagination, web-scraping, scrapy

My goal is to extract all 25 rows ( 6 items per row) per page then iterate over each of the 40 pages.

Currently, my spider extracts the first row from page 1-3 (see CSV output image).

I assumed the, `list_iterator()` function would iterate over each row; however,  there appears to be an error in either my `rules` or `list_iterator()` function that is not allowing all rows per page to be scrapped.

Any assistance or advice is greatly appreciated!

propub_spider.py:

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor 
from propub.items import PropubItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class propubSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'prop$'
    allowed_domains = ['https://projects.propublica.org']
    max_pages = 40
    start_urls = [
        'https://projects.propublica.org/docdollars/search?state%5Bid%5D=33',
        'https://projects.propublica.org/docdollars/search?page=2&state%5Bid%5D=33',
        'https://projects.propublica.org/docdollars/search?page=3&state%5Bid%5D=33']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\\search?page=\\d')), 'parse_start_url', follow=True),)

    def list_iterator(self):
        for i in range(self.max_pages):
            yield Request('https://projects.propublica.org/docdollars/search?page=d' % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="payments_list"]/tbody'):
            item = PropubItem()
            item['payee'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[1]/a[2]/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]/@href').extract()
            item['city'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['state'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[3]/text()').extract()
            item['company'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[4]').extract()
            item['amount'] =  sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[7]/span/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

pipelines.py:

```
import csv

class PropubPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('C:\Users\Desktop\propub.csv', 'wb'))
        self.myCSV.writerow(['payee', 'link', 'city', 'state', 'company', 'amount'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.myCSV.writerow([item['payee'][0].encode('utf-8'), 
        item['link'][0].encode('utf-8'), 
        item['city'][0].encode('utf-8'), 
        item['state'][0].encode('utf-8'),
        item['company'][0].encode('utf-8'),
        item['amount'][0].encode('utf-8')])
        return item
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PropubItem(scrapy.Item):
    payee = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    city = scrapy.Field()
    state = scrapy.Field()
    company = scrapy.Field()
    amount =  scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

CSV output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things need to be fixed:

- use `start_requests()` method instead of `list_iterator()`
- there is a missing `%` here:

  ```
  yield Request('https://projects.propublica.org/docdollars/search?page=%d' % i, callback=self.parse)
  #                                                                 HERE^
  ```
- you don't need `CrawlSpider` since you are providing the pagination links via `start_requests()` - use regular `scrapy.Spider`
- it would more reliable if XPath expressions would match the cells by class attributes

Fixed version:

```
import scrapy

from propub.items import PropubItem


class propubSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'prop$'
    allowed_domains = ['projects.propublica.org']
    max_pages = 40

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.max_pages):
            yield scrapy.Request('https://projects.propublica.org/docdollars/search?page=%d' % i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="payments_list"]//tr[@data-payment-id]'):
            item = PropubItem()
            item['payee'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="name_and_payee"]/a[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="name_and_payee"]/a[1]/@href').extract()
            item['city'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="city"]/text()').extract()
            item['state'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="state"]/text()').extract()
            item['company'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="company"]/text()').extract()
            item['amount'] = sel.xpath('td[@class="amount"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Thanks Alecxe!  I ran the fixed version, and the CSV output is 13 rows of the correct items from a general search (vs. the state specific results, which I assume the "start_urls" filtered for). Also, I received the following error (see, "edit: new error." Thus, it looks like I need to fix three aspects: 1. re-filter the start "urls" for the state-specific results, 2. iterate 25 rows per page, 3. pagination on all 40 pages.  Any ideas?

Comment: "Edit: Error message:"          "File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\propub\propub\pipelines.py", line 22, in process_item
            item['amount'][0].encode('utf-8')])
        exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @EricJohn okay, I've updated the `parse()` callback fixing your XPath expressions, check it out.